# Find parameters in an SIR model

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions, parameters

```
(*total size of population*)
 n = 11000000;
times = 100;
Ipeak = n*0.08
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Mu]*s[t],
   i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*i[t],
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*r[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 
   0, times}, {\[Beta], \[Gamma],\[Mu]}]



(*Extract the infected values from the solution*)
infectedValues = i /. sol;
```

The code so far works. When I try to calculate the parameters $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\mu$ , Mathematica just Running

```
objective[b_, g_, m_] := 
 Norm[(infectedValues[b, g, m][times] - Ipeak)]^2
bDom = Range[0, 2, 0.01];
gDom = Range[0, 1, 0.01];
mDom = Range[0, 1, 0.01];
res = Flatten[Table[{b, g, m, objective[b, g, m]}, {b, bDom}, {g, gDom}, {m, gDom}], 1];
Flatten[res[[PositionSmallest[res[[All, 4]]]]]] // Most
```

I am looking for results with 3 significant figures

Comment: What is the definition of `sol`?

Comment: @Syed I have updated the post.

Comment: You have around 2,000,000 elements in `res` which takes time.  For debugging change the `0.01` to `0.1`.  Then it's easier to see that you need `Flatten[.....,2]` rather than `Flatten[....,1]`.

Comment: @JimB Thank you very much

Comment: `SameQ[res[All, 4]]` gives `True`, so other than the indices, everything is the same in the last column.

Comment: `infectedValues[b, g, m][times]` is too small,almost equal to `0`. and `Ipeak ` is too large.

Comment: @Syed `SameQ[res[[All,4]]` does result in `True` but the minimum is 2.16903*10^11 and the maximum is 1.02414*10^14.  Something does seem about the results. cvgmt points to the culprit(s).

Comment: @cvgmt is there any other way to calculate those parameters? i know that $\mu=0.006$ and $\gamma=0.194$ and i want to calculate $\beta$ for Ipeak

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE*, specific title... yours could apply to nearly every post ever made to this site.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork oK I did that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
NMinimize[{objective[β, γ, μ], 2 > β > 0, 
  1 > γ > 0, 1 > μ > 0}, {β, γ, μ}]
```

> `{8.04071*10^-8, {β -> 1.13891, γ -> 0.0169596, μ ->  0.0109795}}`

Comment: If =0.006 and =0.194 are known  could I search only for   ?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos  No such `β` since  the error too large.  `NMinimize[{objective[β, γ, μ] /. {μ -> 
     0.006, γ -> 0.194}}, {β}]`

Comment: Oh I  understood